# What are SVG Sprites?

Tags: svg, sprite

I know what are image sprites. Just want to know is there any difference between image sprites and SVG sprites??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scalable Vector Graphics is a file format. It describes sprite as vectors store in XML format. Because it is described as vectors you could scale the image without loose precision, it preserves the shape of the graphics.

You can find some explanations on wikipedia:
http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics

Graphic difference between SVG and PNG:
http://www.streamhead.com/vector-vs-bitmap-side-by-side-svg-png-in-flash/